# how to capture x axis and y-axis value in anychart

Tags: reactjs, anychart

I want to capture the x-axis and y-axis values when I click on axes in the console I want to show the values when I click on axes.

example this way :

```
chart.listen("click",function(){
chart.xAxis("{%value}");
console.log(xAxis.value(0));
});
```

It's not showing any value in the console I just want to get value when I click on xAxis or yAxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a `click` handler for individual labels, e.g.:

```
const xAxis = chart.xAxis();
xAxis.labels().listen('click', function (e) {
    const labelIndex = e.labelIndex;
    const label = this.getLabel(labelIndex);
    const value = xAxis.scale().ticks().get()[labelIndex];
    console.log(value);
});
```

You can see it in action in this [playground](https://playground.anychart.com/4u0CwGb1/2) (click on any xAxis label and its value will be logged to the console)